# knowing whether a php script is still running

Tags: php, cron, centos

I've got a bunch of php scripts scheduled to run every couple of minutes in cron on a CentOS machine. I would like for every script to self check if the previous instance of it is still running when it starts and stop if it is.

Comment: Use a lock file like mentioned below, or use a database, which can do more than a lock file, such as store statistic: start/stop time, manual cron starts, it also supports locking.

Answer (score 3):

I do this to manage tasks and making sure they only run one at a time

```
public function startTask($taskname)
{
    $running = "running";
    $lockfile = $taskname . "RUNNING";
    file_put_contents($lockfile, $running);
}

public function endTask($taskname)
{
    $lockfile = $taskname . "RUNNING";
    unlink($lockfile);
}

public function isTaskRunning($taskname)
{
    $lockfile = $taskname . "RUNNING";
    if (file_exists($lockfile))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You call `startTask('name')` when you start the task and then `endTask('name')` when you finish. And on the first line of the task you use

```
if (isTaskRunning('name')) {
   die('already running');
}
```

Put these in a config class or something thats included in all task files and your away

Comment: Nice, quite an ingenious solution. Will definitely use it from now on.

Comment: @VladPreda nice and simple ... :-)

Comment: needs unlink rights on php... choose your apache user carefully!

Comment: @Sebas The OP is running a script using the CRONTAB not a web server ... but I take your point

Comment: you're right, silly me, that's actually probably the reason why he performs the unlink that way.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lock file:

```
<?php
$lockfile = "/tmp/lock.txt";
$fp = fopen($lockfile, "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // acquire an exclusive lock
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, sprintf("Started: %s\nPID: %s", date(), getmypid()));

    // perform your tasks here.

    fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!\nCheck $lockfile for more info.";
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: So you copy and paste this code into every task ? just say they have 20 tasks ? what happens when you want to change the temporary file name ?

Comment: @ManseUK uh... create some functions in an include file? define an object? *edit the code to fit their needs*? I don't recall saying "this is the exact code snippet you *will use*, and you are never allowed to modify it". It's a basic example to demonstrate functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are using a database you can do a database `Named Lock` like this:

```
<?php

$process = "myProcess";

$sql = mysql_query("select get_lock('$process', 0)");
$got_lock = (bool)mysql_fetch_array($sql)[0];

// If process is already running exit
if(!$got_lock){
    echo "Process running";
    exit;
}

// Run my process
for($i=0;$i<100000000;$i++){
    echo $i;
}

// Release the lock
mysql_query("select release_lock('$process')");
```

This form of locking is called a `named lock`, it doesn't "Lock" the database, it just creates a "Named Lock" and when you call it it checks to see if the name exists. It is nothing like a `table lock` or `row lock` It was built into mysql for other applications, such as this.

You can have as many locks as you need, and they are automatically released once the application ends, such as your client disconnecting from mysql: process finishes, php breaks/crashes, mysql crashes (not 100% sure on this one), etc.

Comment: So you can update column to 1 and then to 0... if is zero, second script can run...

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your PHP script a simple echo at the end (maybe with date()) which will be visible in your cron logs and shows you if the script reaches the end (and then finish its task)

Comment: And how does that fulfill the OPs request of *every script to self check* ?

Comment: Well, the script can check the logfile searching of that 'echo at the end' string to state if the instance before has finished or not. BTW I upvoted your answer, I find it more 'organized ^^'